# Trying to make Elavate zoom Adaptative

Tags: responsive-design, zooming

im making a website for my girlfriend,she sales bags
,and i use elevatezoom for the products but i can not get it to adapt to the screen size

```js
<script>
$("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({gallery:'cartera',zoomType:'inner', cursor: 'pointer',responsive: true, containInnerZoom: true, galleryActiveClass: 'active', imageCrossfade: true,zoomSizeMode:'image', loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'});
</script>
```

```css
#sologrande {
 width: 50%;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: auto;
 float: left;
 max-width:500px;
}
.wrapper{
 max-width: 1000px;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #FFF;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
```

```html
  
<div class="wrapper"> 
<div id="sologrande">  
    <img src="small/image1.png" name="zoom_01"  id="zoom_01" 
     data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg"  >
    </div>
</div>
```

and it is not adjusting.

Thank u

Comment: Could your be more specific? If I understood correctly, you want the zoom window do adapt to the screen width, e.g. on smartphone?

Comment: Yes i want the zoom cloud to adjust like a image would if i put e.g 50%,The cloud zoom image always stays the same size eve thought the wrapper (solo grande) adjust to the 50% of the width

Answer (score 0):

I succesfuly reproduced the bug and recorded it

**The bugged version under this link:**

http://mikemoney.nazwa.pl/elevate/demo-before.html

**Bug recorded on smartphone, watch under this link:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lbqgy1bna6ee64/bugged.mov?dl=0

**FIXED EXAMPLE**

http://mikemoney.nazwa.pl/elevate/demo.html

**Solution:**

To fix the problem you need to refresh elevate every time when CSS @media queries change image's width.

To solve the problem I used jQuery Mobile library to handle orientation change event and jQuery to handle resize. I made simple example.

First I add two CSS breakpoints for screen sizes between 240px-320px and 321px-640px. This will adapt image width to the screen size. To target other smartphones with different resolutions and screen sizes it's recommended to add more @media queries. But this is only short example.

```
    /*Target devices 240px - 320px width*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 320px) {

        #zoom_01 {
            width:200px;
        }

    }

    /*Target devices 321px - 640px*/
    @media only screen and  (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 640px) {

        #zoom_01 {
            width:300px ;
        }

    }
```

Than we need to be sure, that elevate zoom will be refreshed in two cases:

1) On orientation change

```
    $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function() {

    });
```

2) On window width change

```
    $( window ).on( "resize", function() {

    });
```

Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>jQuery elevateZoom Demo</title>
    <script src="http://mikemoney.nazwa.pl/elevate/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mikemoney.nazwa.pl/elevate/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #sologrande {
            width: 50%;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-left: auto;
            float: left;
            max-width:500px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 14px;
            color:royalblue;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        p {
            font-size:12px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-weight: bold;
            color:#222222;
        }
        p.mobile, p.landscape {
            display: none;

        }

        p#status {
            color:goldenrod;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .wrapper{
            max-width: 1000px;
            margin:0 auto;
            background:#dcdcdc;
        }

        #zoom_01 {
            width:411px;
        }
        /*Target devices 240px - 320px width*/
        @media only screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 320px) {
            p.mobile
            {
                display: block;
                color:red;
            }
            #zoom_01 {
                width:200px;
            }

        }

        /*Target devices 321px - 640px*/
        @media only screen and  (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 640px) {
            p.landscape
            {
                display: block;
                color:red;
            }

            #zoom_01 {
                width:300px ;
            }

        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>[FIXED VERSION]</h1>
<p class="mobile">Mode: <strong>Portrait</strong> (max-width: 320px)</p>
<p class="landscape">Mode: <strong>Landscape</strong> (min-width: 321, max-width: 720px)</p>
<p id="imgWidth">Image width</p>
<p id="status">Status: Just loaded...</p>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="sologrande">
        <img src="http://mikemoney.nazwa.pl/elevate/images/small/image1.png" name="zoom_01"  id="zoom_01" data-zoom-image="http://mikemoney.nazwa.pl/elevate/images/large/image1.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>


<script>
    $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({gallery:'cartera',zoomType:'inner', cursor: 'pointer',responsive: true, containInnerZoom: true, galleryActiveClass: 'active', imageCrossfade: true,zoomSizeMode:'image', loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'});

    //Triggered when orientation is changed.
    $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function() {
        var windowWidth = $( window ).width(), // get window width
                imgWidth = $( "#zoom_01").width(); // get image width
        //Init elevateZoom
        $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({gallery:'cartera',zoomType:'inner', cursor: 'pointer',responsive: true, containInnerZoom: true, galleryActiveClass: 'active', imageCrossfade: true,zoomSizeMode:'image', loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'});
        //display status
        $( "#status" ).html("Status: Orientation changed!.");
        //display image and window width
        $( "#imgWidth" ).html("Image width: " + imgWidth + "px" + "<br />" + "Window width: " + windowWidth + "px");

    });
    //Triggered when window width is changed.
    $( window ).on( "resize", function() {
        var windowWidth = $( window ).width(), // get window width
                imgWidth = $( "#zoom_01").width(); // get image width
        //Init elevateZoom
        $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({gallery:'cartera',zoomType:'inner', cursor: 'pointer',responsive: true, containInnerZoom: true, galleryActiveClass: 'active', imageCrossfade: true,zoomSizeMode:'image', loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'});
        //display status
        $( "#status" ).html("Status: Window resized!.");
        //display image and window width
        $( "#imgWidth" ).html("Image width: " + imgWidth + "px" + "<br />" + "Window width: " + windowWidth + "px");
    });

    //Triggered on document ready
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var windowWidth = $( window ).width(), // get window width
                imgWidth = $( "#zoom_01").width(); // get image width
        //Init elevateZoom
        $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({gallery:'cartera',zoomType:'inner', cursor: 'pointer',responsive: true, containInnerZoom: true, galleryActiveClass: 'active', imageCrossfade: true,zoomSizeMode:'image', loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'});
        //display status
        $( "#status" ).html("Status: Just loaded!");
        //display image and window width
        $( "#imgWidth" ).html("Image width: " + imgWidth + "px" +  "<br />" + "Window width: " + windowWidth + "px");
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u for the answer,the problem is when you hover on the image,you can see te zoom overflows the wrapper,you can check it on your demo.

Comment: To be clear. The problem occurs only on mobile deivce, right? Could you take a screenshot to show me this negative overflow effect that occurs on your mobile device? Indeed the <div class="zoomWindowContainer"> has dimensions 400x400px while image has 411x274px, but on my phone it looks just fine. It behaves exactly the same as on desktop. The only difference is the cursor. When I get back to home I will grab video from my iPhone and share it with you so maybe it would help me reproduce the bug.

Comment: I added screenshots to my answer. It's updated. Please let me know if it gonna help. I can still record the video, but maybe now you can show   what do you want to acheive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer again,when the window gets smaller than 500px the zoom contain overflows the original image,you can check it on the demo you made,i think the reason it works well on your iphone is that the resolution is bigger than 500px,so that doesnt happend

Comment: In my solution, when browser width is smaller than 500px, it fires CSS styles that set <img> width to 300px. So the image is adapted on to 320px wide iPhone. That's it. Check my video and give me your feedback. I still don't know on what smartphone you test my demo. You haven't provided any screenshot. Only thing I knew it doesn't work for you. I couldn't help you without more details from you.
Could you please vote up for my answers that were helpufl for you?

Comment: Here is recorded video for you, showing step by step what I have  accomplished and how @media queries works (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xu4bxbg2126zg9k/zoom.avi?dl=0).

Comment: Yo can see fron 00:15 to 00:18 that the zoom image overflows the regular image,i've tried it mostly on samsung phones,i havent tried it on my cause i dont own one right now,my galaxy grand has been stoled,

Comment: Indeed. Alright, I made a lot of changes in the code - see my updated answer. Hopefuly it gonna works, but remember, that this example is made for iPhone resolution, so you need to edit @media quries to match your smartphone that you use for testing.

Comment: Thank u for the answer and the solution!!.im a self-taught programer, actually i'm graduating as a Graphic designer,so this code is a little bit more complicated,i cant vote up your answer,i dont have have enought points :S-